# Problems creating a horizontal bar chart using Javascript. Can't figure out my error, esp. why the sample json file is not being pulled?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, plotly

Am I to create a horzontal bar chart to display the top 10 datapoints when an individual's ID is selected from a dropdown menu on the webpage. Not sure where my code is incorrect.

Grabbed a reference to the dropdown select element
Used the list of sample names to populate the select options

```
  function init() {
  var selector = d3.select("#selDataset");


  d3.json("samples.json").then((data) => {
    var sampleNames = data.names;

    sampleNames.forEach((sample) => {
      selector
        .append("option")
        .text(sample)
        .property("value", sample);
    });
```

Used the first sample from the list to build the initial plots

```
    var firstSample = sampleNames[0];
    buildCharts(firstSample);
    buildMetadata(firstSample);
  });
}
```

Initialize the dashboard & fetched new data each time a new sample is selected

```
init();

function optionChanged(newSample) {

  buildMetadata(newSample);
  buildCharts(newSample);
  
}
```

Demographic panel. Filtered the data for the object with the desired sample number. Then used d3 to select the panel with id of '#sample-metadata'

```
function buildMetadata(sample) {
  d3.json("samples.json").then((data) => {
    var metadata = data.metadata;

    var resultArray = metadata.filter(sampleObj => sampleObj.id == sample);
    var result = resultArray[0];

    var PANEL = d3.select("#sample-metadata");


    PANEL.html("");


    Object.entries(result).forEach(([key, value]) => {
      PANEL.append("h6").text(`${key.toUpperCase()}: ${value}`);
    });

  });
}
```

Used buildCharts function to create chart and d3.json to load and retrieve the samples.json file.

```
function buildCharts(sample) {
  
  d3.json("samples.json").then((data) => {

    var data = [barData];


    var samples = data.samples.filter(s => s.id.toString() === id)[0];
```

Created variables to hold objects and sample values.

```
    var ids = result.otu_ids;
    var labels = result.otu_labels;
    var values = result.sample_values;

    console.log(ids);
    console.log(labels);
    console.log(values);
```

Created the yticks for the bar chart

```
    var yticks = otu_ids.slice(0,10).map(otuID => 'OTU ${otuID}').reverse();
```

Created the trace for the bar chart.

```
    var barData = [{
      type: 'bar',
      x: values.slice(0,10),
      y: ids.slice(0,10).reverse(),
      text: ids.slice(0,10).reverse(),
      Orientation: 'h'
    }];

    console.log(yticks);
    console.log(values.slice(0,10));
    console.log(bardata);
```

Created the layout for the bar chart.

```
    var barLayout = {
      title: "Top 10 Bacteria Cultures Found"
     
    };
```

Used Plotly to plot the data with the layout.

```
    Plotly.newPlot('bar-plot', barData, barLayout);

  });
}
```

Error screen shot:

[image]

Comment: While you've done a good job of explaining your code; could you create a reproducible sample?  Also, what specific errors are you seeing?  What does `why the sample JSON file is not being pulled` mean?

Comment: In addition to a [example], as Mark suggests, it is important to let us know what error messages show up in the browser console, or what the network panel shows as the request and response are for `samples.json`.

Comment: @Mark attaching a link to show the error.  http://127.0.0.1:5500

Comment: Attaching a link to show the error.  http://127.0.0.1:5500
No bar chart is uploaded on the webpage and...
when inspecting the page I get 

'ReferenceError: Can't find variable: buildCharts'....
plots.js !Line 19:17 can't find variable: buildCharts

I hope this helps clarify my issue which I do not know how to debug.

Thank you Mark & Randy

Comment: @GAQ, the error seems pretty self explanatory; `buildCharts` function is not defined.  Where are you defining it?  It doesn't appear to be in `plots.js`; so I'm guessing it's in `charts.js`?